# Is it possible to do personal instance segmentation and use the obtained network from the Google API Vision to run it outside the cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I can't find those information on the Google API Vision documentation:

1. Is it possible to create my whole mask R-CNN network and train it with my own images to do instance segmentation with this API? (not generic images)
2. In addition, do I own the obtained network (and data)? And can I use it outside the cloud (onboard system for example)?

Thank to you if you know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Cloud Vision API allows users to classify images into categories, appropriate for multiple common use cases and it has a pre-built, pre-trained machine-learning model. So Google Vision API will not allow you to create your own R-CNN networking.

As you have more specialized requirements and need to create your own R-CNN networking, you should try instead using the [Google Cloud Machine Learning Engine(Cloud ML)](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/), the managed service for building and running machine-learning models at scale using one of TensorFlow, scikit-learn and XGBoost deep-learning framework on Google Cloud.

Models trained using Cloud ML Engine can be downloaded for local execution or mobile integration.